# tensor配列の要素のある場所を取得したいです．

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

tensor型の配列のインデックスを取得したいのですが，うまくいかず，教えて頂きたいです．以下のような形になっており，最大要素1がある場所だけを抽出したいです．

```
tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],  →この場合は0を
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...,
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])　　→この場合は2を
```

コード

```
import numpy as np
import torch                                                                                   
npzfile = np.load("C:/Users/namae/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/myo-armband-nn-master/data/train_set.npz")
x = npzfile['x']
y = npzfile['y']                                                                                     
x = x.astype(np.float32)
x = torch.from_numpy(x).clone()
x = torch.tensor(x)
x = x.clone().detach()
y = y.astype(np.float32)
y = torch.from_numpy(y).clone()
print(y)
```

Comment: `torch.tensor` 型ではなく `numpy.array` 型であれば `np.where(x == 1.0)[1]` になります。

Answer (score 1):

```
x = torch.tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])

x.max(dim=1)[1]
# tensor([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

[`argmax()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.argmax.html)を使いましょう。

```py
x = torch.tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])

x.argmax(1)
# tensor([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2])
```